# Where is the trash icon?

Tags: system

Sorry for the silly question, but where is the trash icon on Juno? How do i add it to the dock?

I'm currently delete things manually by going into the .local/share/trash. But it would be nice to use the icon directly from the desktop.

Thank you.
Ahn

Answer (score 4):

You have two options:

- In Files, there is a trash icon on the left pane which you can empty with the right-click
- You can also ctrl + right-click on the Plank and go to Preferences -> Docklets where you can drag&drop Trash icon on Plank and there, with the right-click, do even more "trashy" things ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently automating my entire Elementary OS installation, and you have this other option

```
touch $HOME/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/trash.dockitem
sed -i 's%Launcher=%Launcher=docklet://trash%g' $HOME/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/trash.dockitem
killall plank
```

---

## Explanation

### LINE 1

I create blank shortcut in the plank config launcher folder

```
touch $HOME/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/trash.dockitem
```

the file will automatically have the following content:

```
#This file auto-generated by Plank.
#2019-...

[PlankDockItemPreferences]
#The uri for this item.
Launcher=
```

### LINE 2

To replace the good option I use `sed`, I had to use the method with `%` instead of `'` because there are `/` in the string to replace

Good option : docklet://trash

```
sed -i 's%Launcher=%Launcher=docklet://trash%g' $HOME/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/trash.dockitem
```

### LINE 3

We are restart `plank`, this is the only way I've found for the icon to get started without restarting

```
killall plank
```

---

**Note** : I do not think killing `plank` processes like that is a good idea, you can reboot the system and normally the icon will appear, it will have all the property of a real trash : filled when there is content, empty when it is empty, the menu of the trash when we do a right click on it.